# Como puedo mantener fijo un menú en la cabecera de mi aplicación cuando esta suba?

Tags: android, menú

soy nuevo en esto y tengo una duda con el diseño de un menú en android.Podrán ayudarme? Lo que quiero es que el menú se mantenga en la parte superior de la pantalla cuando esta suba, así como en play store. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Poné lo que hayas probado hacer con CoordinatorLayout, AppbarLayout, CollapsingLayout, y Toolbar en un theme sin ActionBar para que te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El efecto que deseas se llama "Parallax".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes realizarlo usando un ListView definiendo un header y los elementos que se moverían sobre la imagen principal:

```
  /* Add list view header */
        listView.addHeaderView(listHeader);

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                //No action!
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                /* Check if the first item is already reached to top.*/
                if (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
                    View firstChild = listView.getChildAt(0);
                    int topY = 0;
                    if (firstChild != null) {
                        topY = firstChild.getTop();
                    }
                    heroImageView.setY(topY * 0.5f);
                }
            }
        });
```

Revisa un [ejemplo completo](https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-ListView-and-Parallax/)

Otra forma es usando un [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

o bien un [CoordinatorLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout)

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/rvToDoList"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/rvToDoList"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa esta información:

[Manipulación de Scrolls con CoordinatorLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)

Comment: Gracias, eso era lo que quería!

Comment: Excelente @PaulXD , saludos.